# how to add divider to dataGrid material ui And rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have dataGrid and I want to use **Vertical** `Divider` for Header and cells for Resize like XGrid
[image]
**DataGrid**

```
<Table dir aria-label="collapsible table">
    <TableHead align="right">
        <TableRow>
            {cols}
        </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
    <TableBody>
        {rows}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

**Cells**

```
cols.push(
    <TableCell key='101' align="right">{Some Data}</TableCell>
);
```

**Rows**

```
rows.push(
    <TableRow key={index}>
        {cols}
    </TableRow>
)
```

Comment: For your ref. Check here once: https://material-ui.com/components/dividers/

Comment: @bhartiparmar hi tnx i add image and more details

Comment: see this [Link](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#data-table)

Comment: @A.R.SEIF tnx man tnx